# Преобразовать переменную в числовую и изменить условия скрипта для input'a

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Делаю скрипт для отслеживания расстояния и столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу правильно сделать отсчет если расстояние больше 10 
км.

[image: Картинка-пример]
если расстояние от 0 до 10 я отнимаю по 1км (это работает), если же расстояние от 10 до 50 я хочу прибавлять по 4 к каждому шагу, таким образом как раз получится 50км. Прикрепляю мой код снизу чтобы вы лучше поняли в чем тут суть.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="filter__distance-input" id="step" type="range" min="0" max="21" value="10">
<br>
<label id="step_counter">10</label>

<script>
$('#step').bind('change mousemove', function(){
    let thisStep = $(this).val();
    thisStep = Math.floor(thisStep <= 10 ? thisStep : thisStep+4);
    $('#step_counter').text(thisStep);
});
</script>
```

Я думаю что нужно преобразовать текст из label в числовую переменную и все. Но возможно вы сможете предложить и другой вариант? Заранее всем благодарен за ответы!

Comment: `parseInt(thisStep)` - преобразовали в число и может складывать `parseInt(thisStep) + 4`

Comment: Оно все равно прибавляет 11 к стрингу почему-то. Попробуйте сами. Получается 114, 124 и так далее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно преобразовать значение `input` из строки в число

```js
$('#step').on('change mousemove', function() {
  let thisStep = Number($(this).val());
  if (thisStep > 10) {
    thisStep = 10 + 4 * (thisStep - 10);
  }
  $('#step_counter').text(thisStep);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="filter__distance-input" id="step" type="range" min="0" max="21" value="10">
<br>
<label id="step_counter">10</label>
```

Comment: Кажется, ТС хотел прибавлять по 4 к *каждому шагу*.

Comment: Спасибо большое!